# Three.js rotate a sphere that's followed by a camera

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm working on a toy Three.js scene in which I want to follow a sphere with a camera [[demo]](https://bl.ocks.org/duhaime/801daaa005c373eab6847741bd3f497a). Right now, though, I can't figure out how to make the sphere "roll" without also rotating the camera.

Here's the code I use to update the sphere's position each frame:

```
function moveSphere() {
  var delta = clock.getDelta(); // seconds
  var moveDistance = 200 * delta; // 200 pixels per second
  var rotateAngle = Math.PI / 2 * delta; // pi/2 radians (90 deg) per sec

  // move forwards/backwards/left/right
  if ( pressed['W'] ) {
    sphere.translateZ( -moveDistance );
  }
  if ( pressed['S'] ) 
    sphere.translateZ(  moveDistance );
  if ( pressed['Q'] )
    sphere.translateX( -moveDistance );
  if ( pressed['E'] )
    sphere.translateX(  moveDistance ); 

  // rotate left/right/up/down
  var rotation_matrix = new THREE.Matrix4().identity();
  if ( pressed['A'] )
    sphere.rotateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0), rotateAngle);
  if ( pressed['D'] )
    sphere.rotateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0), -rotateAngle);
  if ( pressed['R'] )
    sphere.rotateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0), rotateAngle);
  if ( pressed['F'] )
    sphere.rotateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0), -rotateAngle);
}
```

And the code to follow the sphere each tick of time:

```
function moveCamera() {
  var relativeCameraOffset = new THREE.Vector3(0,50,200);
  var cameraOffset = relativeCameraOffset.applyMatrix4(sphere.matrixWorld);
  camera.position.x = cameraOffset.x;
  camera.position.y = cameraOffset.y;
  camera.position.z = cameraOffset.z;
  camera.lookAt(sphere.position);
}
```

Is there an easy way to make the ball roll without making the camera spiral all over the place? Inside of the `if (pressed['W'])` block, I tried various permutations of `sphere.rotateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,1), rotateAngle);` but haven't found a natural way to make the ball roll. I would be very grateful for any advice others can offer on this!

Comment: Related: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/making-a-ball-rotate-in-the-direction-it-is-moving/751

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key here was to create a sphere, then add that sphere to a group, so that I could translate and rotate the group (which controls the ball's position) while also rotating the sphere inside the group (which allows the ball to "roll"). Separating these entities out allows the camera to follow the sphere group just as before while allowing the ball to rotate independently of the sphere group's movement [[updated demo](https://bl.ocks.org/duhaime/801daaa005c373eab6847741bd3f497a)]:

```js
  /**
  * Generate a scene object with a background color
  **/

  function getScene() {
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x111111);
    return scene;
  }

  /**
  * Generate the camera to be used in the scene. Camera args:
  *   [0] field of view: identifies the portion of the scene
  *     visible at any time (in degrees)
  *   [1] aspect ratio: identifies the aspect ratio of the
  *     scene in width/height
  *   [2] near clipping plane: objects closer than the near
  *     clipping plane are culled from the scene
  *   [3] far clipping plane: objects farther than the far
  *     clipping plane are culled from the scene
  **/

  function getCamera() {
    var aspectRatio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, aspectRatio, 0.1, 10000);
    camera.position.set(0,150,400);
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);  
    return camera;
  }

  /**
  * Generate the light to be used in the scene. Light args:
  *   [0]: Hexadecimal color of the light
  *   [1]: Numeric value of the light's strength/intensity
  *   [2]: The distance from the light where the intensity is 0
  * @param {obj} scene: the current scene object
  **/

  function getLight(scene) {
    var lights = [];
    lights[0] = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 0.6, 0 );
    lights[0].position.set( 100, 200, 100 );
    scene.add( lights[0] );

    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x111111);
    scene.add(ambientLight);
    return light;
  }

  /**
  * Generate the renderer to be used in the scene
  **/

  function getRenderer() {
    // Create the canvas with a renderer
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
    // Add support for retina displays
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    // Specify the size of the canvas
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    // Add the canvas to the DOM
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    return renderer;
  }

  /**
  * Generate the controls to be used in the scene
  * @param {obj} camera: the three.js camera for the scene
  * @param {obj} renderer: the three.js renderer for the scene
  **/

  function getControls(camera, renderer) {
    var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    controls.zoomSpeed = 0.4;
    controls.panSpeed = 0.4;
    return controls;
  }

  /**
  * Get grass
  **/

  function getPlane(scene, loader) {
    var texture = loader.load('grass.jpg');
    texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping; 
    texture.repeat.set( 10, 10 );
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      map: texture, side: THREE.DoubleSide
    });
    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1000, 1000, 10, 10);
    var plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    plane.position.y = -0.5;
    plane.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
    scene.add(plane);
    return plane;
  }

  /**
  * Add background
  **/

  function getBackground(scene, loader) {
    var imagePrefix = 'sky-parts/';
    var directions  = ['right', 'left', 'top', 'bottom', 'front', 'back'];
    var imageSuffix = '.bmp';
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1000, 1000, 1000 ); 
    
    var materialArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
      materialArray.push( new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map: loader.load(imagePrefix + directions[i] + imageSuffix),
        side: THREE.BackSide
      }));
    var sky = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, materialArray );
    scene.add(sky);
  }

  /**
  * Add a character
  **/

  function getSphere(scene) {
    var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 30, 12, 9 );
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      color: 0xd0901d,
      emissive: 0xaf752a,
      side: THREE.DoubleSide,
      flatShading: true
    });
    var sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

    // create a group for translations and rotations
    var sphereGroup = new THREE.Group();
    sphereGroup.add(sphere)

    sphereGroup.position.set(0, 24, 100);
    scene.add(sphereGroup);
    return [sphere, sphereGroup];
  }

  /**
  * Store all currently pressed keys
  **/

  function addListeners() {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
      pressed[e.key.toUpperCase()] = true;
    })
    window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
      pressed[e.key.toUpperCase()] = false;
    })
  }

  /**
  * Update the sphere's position
  **/

  function moveSphere() {
    var delta = clock.getDelta(); // seconds
    var moveDistance = 200 * delta; // 200 pixels per second
    var rotateAngle = Math.PI / 2 * delta; // pi/2 radians (90 deg) per sec

    // move forwards/backwards/left/right
    if ( pressed['W'] ) {
      sphere.rotateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0), -rotateAngle)
      sphereGroup.translateZ( -moveDistance );
    }
    if ( pressed['S'] ) 
      sphereGroup.translateZ(  moveDistance );
    if ( pressed['Q'] )
      sphereGroup.translateX( -moveDistance );
    if ( pressed['E'] )
      sphereGroup.translateX(  moveDistance ); 

    // rotate left/right/up/down
    var rotation_matrix = new THREE.Matrix4().identity();
    if ( pressed['A'] )
      sphereGroup.rotateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0), rotateAngle);
    if ( pressed['D'] )
      sphereGroup.rotateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0), -rotateAngle);
    if ( pressed['R'] )
      sphereGroup.rotateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0), rotateAngle);
    if ( pressed['F'] )
      sphereGroup.rotateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0), -rotateAngle);
  }

  /**
  * Follow the sphere
  **/

  function moveCamera() {
    var relativeCameraOffset = new THREE.Vector3(0,50,200);
    var cameraOffset = relativeCameraOffset.applyMatrix4(sphereGroup.matrixWorld);
    camera.position.x = cameraOffset.x;
    camera.position.y = cameraOffset.y;
    camera.position.z = cameraOffset.z;
    camera.lookAt(sphereGroup.position);
  }

  // Render loop
  function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    moveSphere();
    moveCamera();
  };

  // state
  var pressed = {};
  var clock = new THREE.Clock();

  // globals
  var scene = getScene();
  var camera = getCamera();
  var light = getLight(scene);
  var renderer = getRenderer();

  // add meshes
  var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
  var floor = getPlane(scene, loader);
  var background = getBackground(scene, loader);
  var sphereData = getSphere(scene);
  var sphere = sphereData[0];
  var sphereGroup = sphereData[1];

  addListeners();
  render();
```

```css
body { margin: 0; overflow: hidden; }
canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/88/three.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is this line:

```
var cameraOffset = relativeCameraOffset.applyMatrix4(sphere.matrixWorld);
```

This takes the offset you specify and applies not only the sphere position, but it's *rotation* as well. For example, if your sphere is rotated 180 degrees on the Y-axis, the resulting vector is (0, 50, -200) + (sphere position).

You need to extract the translation component from the sphere matrix, and apply it to the offset. The code below uses an intermediate matrix to store the position of the sphere.

```
    /**
     * Follow the sphere
     **/
    var sphereTranslation = new THREE.Matrix4(); // only make it once to reduce overhead

    function moveCamera() {
        var relativeCameraOffset = new THREE.Vector3(0,50,200);
        sphereTranslation.copyPosition(sphere.matrixWorld); // get sphere position only
        var cameraOffset = relativeCameraOffset.applyMatrix4(sphereTranslation);
        camera.position.x = cameraOffset.x;
        camera.position.y = cameraOffset.y;
        camera.position.z = cameraOffset.z;
        camera.lookAt(sphere.position);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @GregRozmarynowycz for your response. The challenge with this approach is if the ball rotates for turning purposes (ie on press of "A" key) the camera is no longer following the ball. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: This wasn't a clear requirement from your question, please be more specific next time

Comment: Well I did write "I want to follow a sphere with a camera". Sorry if you spent lots of time on this!